# Accessing default value of decorator argument in Python

Tags: python, python-decorators

I am trying to write a custom Python decorator which wraps the decorated function in a `try ... except` block and adds a message with additional context to make debugging easier.

Based on different resources (see [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/decorators-with-parameters-in-python/) and [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/python-decorators-explained-with-examples/) for example) I so far built the following:

```py
def _exception_handler(msg):
    """Custom decorator to return a more informative error message"""
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                # this is the actual decorated function
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                # we catch the exception and raise a new one with the custom
                # message and the original exception as cause
                raise Exception(f"{msg}: {e}") from e
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

This works as expected - if I run:

```py
@_exception_handler("Foo")
def test():
    raise ValueError("Bar")

test()
```

This returns:

```
Exception: Foo: Bar
```

Now, I do not always want to pass a custom `msg` because that's sometimes a bit redundant. So I set a default value of `msg=""` and I want to check if `msg==""` and if that is the case I would just like to re-create the `msg` inside the decorator based on the function name, something like `msg = f"An error occurred in {func.__name__}"`.

I would then like to use the decorator without any `msg` argument. **I do not care about the empty parantheses, using `@_exception_handler()` is perfectly fine for me.**

But somehow this does not seem to work:

```py
def _exception_handler(msg=""):
    """Custom decorator to return a more informative error message"""
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            try:
                # this is the actual decorated function
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                if msg=="":
                    # if no custom message is passed, we just use the function name
                    msg = f"An error occurred in {func.__name__}"
                # we catch the exception and raise a new one with the message
                # and the original exception as cause
                raise Exception(f"{msg}: {e}") from e
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

If I run:

```py
@_exception_handler()
def test():
    raise ValueError("Bar")

test()
```

I get

```
UnboundLocalError: local variable 'msg' referenced before assignment
```

If I put `global message` right below the `def decorator(func):` line, I get the same errors. If I put it below the `def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):`, I instead get:

```
NameError: name 'msg' is not defined
```

Any ideas how I can get this to work? If possible, I would like to avoid any third-party modules such as `wrapt`. Using `wraps` from `functools` from the standard library is fine of course (although I did not have any luck with that so far either).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

add this code `nonlocal msg`.

```
def _exception_handler(msg=""):
    """Custom decorator to return a more informative error message"""
    def decorator(func):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            nonlocal msg
            try:
                # this is the actual decorated function
                func(*args, **kwargs)
            except Exception as e:
                if msg=="":
                    # if no custom message is passed, we just use the function name
                    msg = f"An error occurred in {func.__name__}"
                # we catch the exception and raise a new one with the message
                # and the original exception as cause
                raise Exception(f"{msg}: {e}") from e
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```